# How can i add a img tag inside a li tag with jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a way to replace smileys `:-)` inside a `<li>` tag with jQuery.

Expecting : `<li>Hi! <img class="smile"></img></li>`

Getting : `<li>Hi! <img class="smile"></li>`

Perhaps it has something to do with the manipulation of the DOM. But unfortunately i can't figure out what i'm missing here.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            function apply_smileys(message) {
                // https://regex101.com/r/yS0eM4/1
                var regex_smile = /(:\))|(:-\))|(\(:)|(\(-:)/g;
                message = message.replace(regex_smile,'<img class="smile"></img>');
                return message;
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var message = 'Hi! :)';
                message = apply_smileys(message);
                console.log(message);
                // Hi! <img class="smile"></img>
                $('<li>' + message + '</li>').appendTo('#my_list ul'); 
                // <li>Hi! <img class="smile"></li>
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my_list">
            <ul>
                <li>This is test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting the wrong thing and you are getting the correct/valid one.

`img` tags are self-closing (*they cannot have a closing tag*)

Quoting the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

> **Permitted content**  None, it is an empty element.
>   **Tag omission**    Must have a start tag and must **not** have an end tag.

---

So it would be better to correct your code to

```
message = message.replace(regex_smile,'<img class="smile">');
```

Comment: I first tried to change the <img class="smile"></img> to <img class="smile"/> but then the / is missing and im getting back a unclosed tag. 
<img class="smile">

Comment: Again, img tags are self-closing. You don't need to close them at all.

Comment: @Thomas do not worry. The ending `/` is not required for tags that are not permitted to have a closing tag. So `<img class="smile">` is valid html and what most modern browsers will give.

Comment: Thanks again! should drink more coffee or going to bed. I was too worried about a non existing closing tag :(